# XML Schema - Which Is More Correct?

Tags: c#, xml

supposing O have these two equivalent (at least they are supposed to be) XML schemas.  The actual XML will eventually be parsed by C#.  I think the second way is 'more correct' since I will get attributes as actual attrbutes, instead of child elements, correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<switch>
  <switch_name>switch1</switch_name>
  <software_version>1</software_version>
  <vendor>Cisco</vendor>
  <ip_address>1.1.1.1</ipaddress>
  <linecard>
    <model_type>12345</model_type>
 <fcport>
 <slot> 1</slot>
 <port> 1</port>
 <speed>4</speed>
 </fcport>

  </linecard>
</switch>

<switch>
 <switch name="switch1" version="1" vendor="Cisco" ip_address="1.1.1.1">
     <linecard model="12345">
  <fcport slot="1" port="1" speed="4">
</fcport>
<linecard>
</switch>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither one is strictly more "correct" than the other, both will work for your example. Neither breaks any rules.

That said, I think I agree with [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp) on this one, in that **data** should go inside child elements rather than attributes. Especially things like IP addresses just FEEL like data that should be a child element rather than an attribute. Attributes I typically use for **metadata**, such as auto generated IDs.

This is especially true if you later want to account for expansion -- for example, what if you want to associate multiple IPs? With child elements you can just add another element, but with attributes you have to come up with a new attribute name for each addition (ip1, ip2, ip3...).

Comment: good point on the expansion.  I can already see how that would be an issue for some other data associated with the switch.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are no "right" way of representing data in XML when choosing between using elements or attributes for properties of an entity. Choose whatever works for you.

Generally elements give more freedom as you may have sub-elements eventually. I.e. if property is list of some sort representing it as comma-separated value in attribute looks very non-XML.

Side note: ["XML schema"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) usually means different thing - structured schema for XML... what you have I'd call "representation of data in XML".

Answer (score 0):

The classic article on how to choose between elements and attributes is here:

http://xml.coverpages.org/elementsAndAttrs.html

I note that at the end of the page it quotes John Cowan quoting me: "Beginnners always ask this question. Those with a little experience express their opinions passionately. Experts tell you there is no right answer'."